# Why do we have trigonometric functions besides $\sin(x)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Probably a terrible question, but I've been curious and can't come up with a reason besides convenience for myself with my limited knowledge.
Why do we have $\cos(x)$, $\tan(x)$, etc. when all of these (from what I understand) can be defined using $\sin(x)$?
Is there an occasion where this is not the case?

Comment: You shouldn't underestimate the value of convenience. Good choice of notation is almost a necessity for a field of mathematics to thrive. In this particular case, there are also historical reasons for the abundance of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Quite often, you need things like $\arctan$, which is hard to remember as "the inverse function of $\sin x/\cos x$."

Comment: In maths, we want easier and easier instead of making things complex. Thats why.

Comment: One could ask why we have more than just $0$ and $1$ because everything that can be expressed in words can be expressed with just $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering! I completely understand the value of convenience in mathematics, and I thought that convenience might by the reason for this. Just wasn't sure (whether logically or not) if there may be some circumstances where this may not be the case. Was not aware of the historical reasons though. I'll have to do some reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically it is convenience and history.  Mind you, there are also a number of trigonometric functions that were used historically but are no longer used, e.g. [versine and haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine).

Comment: Its always a pleasure to browse wikipedia and look for new "sinus look-a-like" functions :)